# spring web flow: how is a request handled?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

In the config file, there are lots of elements: flow-executor, flow-registry, flow-builder-services, viewFactoryCreator, FlowHandlerAdapter, FlowHandlerMapping, etc.

In what order do they work?

When a request comes in, the servelet will dispatch it to a handler, then I guess the spring web flow framework will somehow parse the flow and return a view. But how exactly does the spring web flow framework handle the request? And in what order do those elements defined in the config file work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a nice image of the request lifecycle taken from the [link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?21639-Spring-MVC-Request-Lifecycle-Diagram.). Also [here](http://www.javastuff.in/2011/08/lifecycle-of-request-in-spring-mvc.html) is an article giving you the life-cycle events.

[image: Spring MVC request lifecycle].

Comment: thanks. i have seen this when i was googling. but it does not cover web flow and the elements in the web flow config.

Comment: @CuiPengFei did you find?